# How to Create Custom Azure Service Bus Roles for Both Queue and Topic with Different Permissions in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-worker-roles

I am working on a Terraform project that involves creating custom roles for Azure Service Bus resources. Specifically, I need to create a single custom role that covers both a Service Bus Queue and a Topic, but granting different permissions to each resource.

Is there a way to achieve this using Terraform modules or any other method? I would appreciate any code examples or guidance on how to structure the Terraform configuration to accomplish this task efficiently.

Thank you!

I have attempted to create separate custom roles for the Queue and Topic, but that resulted in duplicated code, which I want to avoid for better maintainability. It duplicated at a point that theres no advantage of using the custom role than the built-in roles

Comment: If I wasn't clear enough, what I want is to have 1 custom role targeting both a Service Bus and a Queue. Each resource within this custom role should have different permissions.

This means you want to create a single custom role that includes both a Service Bus and a Queue, and each of these resources should have distinct permissions within that role.

Comment: Kindly share the code, what you have tried?